# Get a certain number of random words from a string

Tags: php, arrays, string

Like:

```
The quick, brown fox jumps over a lazy dog. DJs flock by when MTV ax quiz prog. Junk MTV quiz graced by fox whelps. Bawds jog, flick quartz, vex nymphs. Waltz, bad nymph, for quick jigs vex! Fox nymphs grab quick-jived waltz. Brick quiz whangs jumpy veldt fox. Bright vixens jump; dozy fowl quack. Quick wafting zephyrs vex bold Jim. Quick zephyrs blow, vexing daft Jim.
```

(this is just sample text, the real one is much longer)

How can I get let's say 5 words from this text?

I tried using `explode(' ', $text);` Then shuffle the array and pick 5 elements from it, but I get all the punctuation and other characters. I just want a-z characters. Also the words need to have at least 3 characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`str_word_count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) for this:

```
$words = str_word_count($str, 1);
shuffle($words);
$selection = array_slice($words, 0, 5);
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/a4ydh)**.

You can also use another way (such as [`array_rand`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)) of picking out random words from the `$words` array if you are concerned about performance; this is just the most convenient.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split):

```
$words = preg_split('#[^a-z0-9]+#', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$key = array_rand($words);
return $words[$key];
```

This will split the string on any sequence of non-alphanumeric characters.

If you work on utf-8 data, try this instead:

```
$words = preg_split('#[^\pL\pN]+#u', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the unwanted characters

```
$words = explode(' ', $string);
$words = array_map (function ($word) {
    trim($word, '.,-:;"\'');
}, $words);
```

and filter by word length

```
$words = array_filter($words, function($word) {
    return strlen($word) > 2;
}, $words);
```

Comment: I would keep the wanted characters, instead ;)

Answer (score 0):

$string = preg_replace("/[^a-z ]+/i", "", $string);

before you do the explode

Comment: This won't work, as it will remove spaces and then `explode` would not work any more.